# Storing visitor data to a DB and associating it with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

So I am working on a client website and the request is, when a visitor submits a form, it should also save some sort of key or data so that when my client looks at a submission record, he can also pull up analytics and see data on the user, such as where they came from, was it paid traffic or organic, etc...

I know Analytics tells you all of this, but what I don't think is possible, is connecting a specific entry to analytics records to show individual data like this. If possible, I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Here are specific steps on how to do this. http://iabramo.com/2016/08/19/measure-user-behavior-google-analytics-sheets-data-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You can store a key (which must not be personally identifiable information, best use a random string) as a custom dimension and store the same string in your external database. That way you can correlate your GA data and external data using your custom dimension als key that joins information from both data sources.

A while ago [I wrote a somewhat lengthy tutorial how to join data from GA with data from Salesforce](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-1/). I think you can use that as a starting point and adapt this for your purposes.

For a site with not to much traffic [this tutorial might also be interesting](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/a-poor-mans-crm-with-ga-and-google-spreadsheets/) - this is a proof of concept on how to use Google Sheets as a backend for forms and join it with Google Analytics data. The principle is the same, have a key field in GA and the spreadsheet and join the data by using that field. Again, you probably do not want to use this as-is, but it might be a useful starting point.